# Forloop for list of dictionaries where looping needs to happen for value in second key of the list

Tags: python

```
final_list =[]

a_list=[{'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:01.560000',
  'filename': '20220214T132301560.jpg'},
 {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:03.840000',
  'filename': '20220214T132303840.jpg'},
 {'convertedDate': '2022-02-14 13:23:07.860000',
  'filename': '20220214T132307860.jpg'}]
```

what should write at 'i' value in the forloop so that I will reach each image files and sotre them in a list.

one such iteration for your reference is as below( 'i' should be file name for example :20220214T132307860.jpg)

```
for i in range(len(a_list):
  img = load_img(i, target_size=(64,64))
  final_list.append(img)
```

Comment: `[d['filename'] for d in a_list]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the images using OpenCV's `cv2.imread` as you iterate through your list. Append each image to `final_list`

```
final_list = []
for d in a_list:
    img = cv2.imread(d['filename'])
    final_list.append(img)
```

Using your `load_img()` you can replicate the following:

```
for i in a_list:
    img = load_img(i['filename'], target_size=(64, 64))
    final_list.append(img)
```